# Wait for PID - shown in ps

Tags: bash, scripts, process

I am using the command below in a script to wait for a PID and then do something when that process finishes: 
`while ps -p [pid] > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done; [cmd]` 
where [pid] is the PID of the running process and [cmd] is the command that I want to execute after it's finished.
Now my question is the following: is there any way to see that my process (the script) is waiting for the process [pid] with a command like ps or somehing else?

Comment: What kind of notification did you have in mind? also: a single notification or a continueing one?

Comment: A continuing one would be better.

Comment: Have to bother you again, you mean a notification *in the terminal* or one on your desktop? (I assumed the last one)

Comment: I guess both would be nice. If you have a solution for any of them, that would be great.Thank you.

Comment: If you're using bash or dash/sh, you should look into the `wait` builtin command (in `man bash` or `help wait`). It waits for one (or many) child jobs to finish, and can probably do everything you're trying to do, at once.

Comment: Alexandra, was one or more answer(s) what you are looking for?

Comment: Your answers were helpful, thank you very much. I will have one more question: In the case that I presented, I know the PID I am waiting for. But in the case of a more complex application, if I have a process that is stuck, is there any way to see that that process is waiting for another one to complete? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Zenity

What can relatively easy be done is to:

- generate a `Zenity` message to mention your script is waiting for a pid to appear.
- The window will be automatically closed if the pid appears in the output of `ps -p <pid>`, `ps -e` or any other `ps` command, run by the script.

  [image]

#### Example

Below is the procedure how it can be done. 
I am using `python` in the example, you can either implement it to bash, or (why not) simply use the python script and run it with your pid as an argument.

#### The principle

1. In a loop, the script checks if the pid is in the output of (in my example) `ps -e`
2. If not, the script calls a `Zenity` window, mentioning you are waiting for the pid

   *note:* The script also checks if the `Zenity` window already exists, with the help of the command:

   ```
   wmctrl -l
   ```

   which lists all windows. If we wouldn't include this step, you would be scattered with popping up windows...

   The command to call the `Zenity` window:

   ```
   zenity --info --title='pid-message' --text='Waiting for pid to appear'
   ```
3. As soon as the pid shows up in `ps -e`, the window closes, with the command:

   ```
   wmctrl -c <windowname>
   ```

#### Alternatively, simply use the script below

If you start the script below before you run your command, it will wait for the pid to appear, while your script runs.

- Install `wmctrl`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  ```
- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `waitfor_pid.py`
- Run it with the command

  ```
  python3 /path/to/waitfor_pid.py <pid>
  ```

*The script*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import time

# the pid you are waiting for, as an argument
pid = sys.argv[1]
# The title of the window; if you change it, make sure it does not have space(s)
window_title = "pid-message"

t = 0 
# the script waits for the pid during 30 seconds, to prevent endless loop if your command is not succesful
while t < 30:
    # check the list of processes
    p_list = subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-e"]).decode("utf-8")
    # check the windowlist, to see if the Zenity window already exists
    if not pid in p_list:
        w_list = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl",  "-l"]).decode("utf-8")
        if not "pid-message" in w_list:
            # if the message window does not exist, call it
            command = "zenity --info --title='"+window_title+"' --text='Waiting for pid "+pid+" to appear'"
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
    else:
        # if the pid appeared, close the message window and break the script
        subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-c", window_title])
        break
    t = t+1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: your python scripts are exemplary I am learning a lot from those. +1 here.

Answer (score 0):

Or just from bash:

`MYPID=$(pidof target) ; zenity -- info --text "Process $MYPID waiting" & wait $MYPID ; killall zenity`

Note that wait requires the process to be a child of the current shell; you could use your original version instead.